# Cypress expectations only work with cy.wait or without cypress-testing-lib within

Tags: cypress, cypress-testing-library

I recently installed `Cypress 10` on a personal project and I was implementing a dummy test to ensure everything works. I decided to go a bit "the extra" mile on the example and I am wondering why the following assertions fail. The scenario is the following: the user types into a search box, and a list of `cultural events` is displayed. The user clicks an anchor on the first one; This causes the page to go from `/` to `/events/:event_id` (most of these things are still hard-coded hence the usage of `.first` when finding items (instead of looking for a specific `listitem`)... Now, the problem arises with the expectations that come after that.

If I add a `cy.wait` expression, the assertions work; If I do not use `cy.wait` **nor** `cypress-testing-library#within`, the assertions work... If I do not use `cy.wait` **and use** `within`, the assertions fail regardless of having or not having timeouts spread all over the code. Note that, I am confident by verification, that the assertions are supposed to be within a `main` HTML element. I have the browser element-inspect open right next to me, as well as the Next code that renders the `<AppLayout>` and sticks the content within the `main` element.

I would like to know the alternatives to `cy.wait` since this is not a very reliable way of waiting for elements to render. Also, if someone can explain the reasoning behind these failings, it would be great.

```js
describe("dummy spec", () => {
  it("passes", () => {
    const testEvent = "networking for introverts";
    const testEventRegExp = new RegExp(testEvent, "i");

    cy.visit("/");

    cy.findByRole("banner").within(() => {
      cy.findByRole("searchbox", { name: /search events/i }).type(`${testEvent}{enter}`);
    });

    cy.findByRole("main").within(() => {
      cy.findAllByRole("listitem")
        .first()
        .within(() => {
          cy.findByRole("link", { name: testEventRegExp }).click();
        });
    });

    cy.location("pathname").should("eq", "/events/e2");

    // Waiting the tinniest bit and the expectations below pass as expected
    // cy.wait(25);

    cy.findByRole("main").within(() => {
      cy.findByRole("heading", { name: testEventRegExp })
        // Assertion fails regardless of specified timeout amount
        .should("be.visible", { timeout: 1000 })
        .contains(testEvent, {
          matchCase: false
        });
      cy.findByTestId("event-summary").should("be.visible");
      cy.findByTestId("event-description").should("be.visible");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would say is 25 ms is nothing compared to the overall test duration (about 1/12 the time of a blink).

Don't be concerned about the principle of `cy.wait()` if it's what makes the test work, but burn-test to make sure you have the right duration.

Since you have a Next app which has React as base framework, and if you use functional components (hooks) you may be able to use `cy.wait(0)`.

Javascript is single-threaded, meaning any code running in the test will hog the thread until blocked by, say a network call or a `setTimeout()`.

Using `wait(0)` blocks the test momentarily and allows the React hooks to complete.

This also fits with your observation that adding timeout does not work.

```js
// Assertion fails regardless of specified timeout amount
.should("be.visible", { timeout: 1000 })
```

However `timeout: 1000` is going the wrong way - normal timeout is `4000` so you want to try `10000`.

Comment: Using `cy.wait(0)` appears to be good enough. Coming from JSDom testing, this is as close as I might be able to get to those `waitFor` async functions. 

It must be what you said; Since `main` is available on `/` and is available on `/events/e2`. By looking for my targets within a `main` element before allowing `Next` to resolve, I am effectively looking for elements within the main that belong to `/` instead of the main that belongs to `/events/e2`, which leads to failure.

Any suggestion on how to look within `/events/e2` main without `waiting`?

Comment: I don't think so, but `wait(0)` is a pretty small wait. Maybe `cypress-testing-library` which is based on `react-testing-library` can do it without the wait. It seems to me that Cypress should have `cy.wait(0)` built in to every command.

Comment: Oh, just noticed you already have `cypress-testing-library`

Answer (score 0):

Using hardcoded wait timer will not address the flakiness of a test and will be troublesome in the longer time frame. Here are a few ways to make a test stronger.

If your app makes an API calls, you can spy, wait on it, and choose to check the response data. This will make your test more resilient and less flaky.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', 'fruit').as('fruit')
// action to redirect user to new page where API call occurs
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/new-url') // good practice
cy.wait('@fruit') //wait until request and response occur
  .its('response.body') // now have access to response body and can make assertions
```

Adding assertions on elements your query will make your tests stronger. Using `.should('be.visible')` will [retry](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#What-you-ll-learn) the previous command
until the element is visible to the user as oppose to the [default assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Default-Assertions) of the element existing in the DOM.

```js
// 
cy.findByRole("main").should('be.visible').within(() => {
  cy.findByRole("heading", { name: testEventRegExp })
    .should("be.visible", { timeout: 1000 })
    .contains(testEvent, {
     matchCase: false
     });
});
```

Comment: Indeed `cy.wait` is not a good option, hence the post. Unfortunately, the page of the event does not make requests, it is statically generated and will remain so for a long while. Consequently, I tried the second suggestion you made, where I added `should("be.visible")` before the `within` expression, as well as on the `cy.findByRole(heading)`, but the test still fails unless `cy.wait` exists in some form. Would it not be expected for `should("be.visible")` to detect the element shortly after the render - since a short wait solves the issue?

Comment: What is even stranger is that, while `cy.findByRole("heading").should("be.visible")` is executing, the browser preview already shows the element being searched for.

However, when the test fails, it renders an HTML markup on the error that corresponds to the previous `/index` page.